# JavaScript - how to remove image drawn to canvas from sprite sheet

Tags: javascript, html

(redneck version of Hello World);

Here's the thing:
 I am in STRICT mode -- &&
 I have a PNG file and a sprite.js file to declare and later define each image or graphic or whatever you want to call it && then in my .html file I have some javascript in there in the body in a script tag && I do this:
    // in the "sprite.js" file...

```
var

//...etc - other stuff here ...

s_text,

//... etc - other stuff here ...

// then lower down I have this...

s_text = {

// says "Level Up !"

  NextLevel: new Sprite(img, 59, 114, 95, 19),  // - "Level Up".
    // other stuff ...
}

//... etc - other stuff here ...  // o.k. && that's it for that file &&
// I have this other file-- html5 w/ javascript in the body tag see ??
// && it says this:

if (currentstate === states.NextLevel) {
    s_text.NextLevel.draw(ctx, width2 - s_text.NextLevel.width/2, height-400);
 // how do I remove this ??

// I need to remove it && re-draw it later when a trigger event happens !!!!!

// I had a klunky way to do this that was not good:

// this works - not so good though.

delete s_text.NextLevel.x && s_text.NextLevel.y;

// "LEVEL UP!" Pic.

//but-- can't reset or make visible again when I have to re-draw it.

// I can draw another one on screen when that one is still there-- but if I 

//delete or delete the .x && .y || set them to 0; I can't get that to draw 

//again && I need to draw it 5 or more times when something triggers it:

if (score >= 15) { // score of 15 triggers this for testing.

s_text.NextLevel.draw(ctx, width2 - s_text.NextLevel.width/2, height-400);

// need to do this again-- but, won't come back up the way I am doing it &&       am ashamed to say-- I don't know how-- am I the only guy in the history of html5 to have to draw, remove and re-draw an image ??
```

I went back and forth through "JavaScript the definative guide" last night til early this morning and could not find what I needed && would be so very greatful for the correct way to do this &&

kind regards, mark pouncey.

Comment: >> ping me at "markpouncey-at-gmail-dot-com" && thanks.

Comment: You can't really "remove" stuff from a canvas; it's like removing paint from a wall. You can clear the whole canvas and redraw the whole scene, or you can draw some background over what you want to erase.